# Is there any way to import the new Facebook SDK 4.11.0 for Android to Eclipse

Tags: android

Is there any way to import the new Facebook SDK 4.11.0 for Android to Eclipse without Gradle or MavenI've been watching some pages but i don't find a the way for this new sdk.

Comment: Better to move to `Android Studio`.

Comment: http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/android/Importing-from-Android-Studio-into-Eclipse

Comment: reason..why you are suggesting studio?? i have only 4 gb ram ram and i3 .so it's difficult to work on studio as more time is consumed in processing ..Is there any method for eclipse

Comment: use android studio...................